# close the soft key pad when i click on other views in android

Tags: android

I want to open the soft key pad when we click on or focus on edit text.Suppose in my application I have one Edittext view and image view at that time when i click on image view automatically the soft key pad will be closed.when i click on or focus on edittext at that time only Soft keypad will be opened what can i do? give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is this: [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/1109108#1109108):

> You can force Android to hide the
>   virtual keyboard using the
>   InputMethodManager, calling
>   hideSoftInputFromWindow, passing in
>   the token of the window containing
>   your edit field.
>
> InputMethodManager imm =
>   (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(),
>   0);
>
> This will force the keyboard to be
>   hidden in all situations. In some
>   cases you will want to pass in
>   InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY
>   as the second parameter to ensure you
>   only hide the keyboard when the user
>   didn't explicitly force it to appear
>   (by holding down menu).

Please search before you post your question.

Answer (score 0):

The method described in the [link mentioned in previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) (where I cannot post this answer because the thread is protected - interesting feature) works, but the answer does not specify WHERE (or WHEN) to execute the mentioned method.

I have had a problem with soft keyboard staying open and visible even when I show completely different view (by calling `Activity.SetContentView(otherView)`. Also, I wanted the keyboard to disappear if a user opens a menu - in general, I wanted the input keyboard really GONE!!! unless user is actively using it (as should be).

The solution I found was overriding the onWindowVisibilityChanged and OnWindowsFocusChanged method of a view that contains the EditText:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

EditText myEditText;


@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    //...

    super.onFinishInflate();
}   


    @Override
protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)_activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
}   

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    if(!hasWindowFocus) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)_activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
}
// ...
}
```

Overriding both will hide the input keyboard in 'most cases'. I still had to repeat the above two lines when implementing the onEditorAction of the EditText callback interface.

Overriding only one of the two methods will make behavior a bit different, test and choose what you want to do.